# AttributeError: module 'subprocess' has no attribute 'c'. What does the c attribute do in subprocess?

Tags: python, subprocess

Im trying to solve a problem where there is a function using `subprocess.c['rnd_string']` but i cant find any information on what the c does. I have two files, both use the same import:

```
*#!/usr/bin/python3
import sys
import subprocess.*
```

The first one works but when i try to use the second file i get the error:

> AttributeError: module 'subprocess' has no attribute 'c'

In the first file it looks like this:

```
subprocess.run(subprocess.c['rnd_string'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

and in the second:

```
subprocess.c['rnd_string2']
```

The file names are a1 and a2 so it shoudn't affect the subprocess import.

Comment: You sure the following code subprocess.run(subprocess.c['rnd_string'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE) actually runs, i.e. executes?

Comment: Does the first file explicitly add some `subprocess.c` attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such method/attribute called `c` in the subprocess module so it's impossible for that to run in your second file.

And as for the first one `subprocess.run(subprocess.c['rnd_string'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)` as you stated doesnt actually executes.

Comment: You were right, the first was never executed! Thanks alot!

Comment: This is not what `*` does. A bare `*` in a function definition marks the start of keyword-only arguments. It does not mean you can pass nonsense expressions as arguments and have them work.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica thanks for the note, had my doubts. Edited my answer :)